# Mouse clicks stop working shortly after login

Tags: windows-10, drivers, user-profiles, mouse-click

I am not sure if this is the right place to ask this but I am really out of ideas:

When I log in (Windows 10), my mouse works fine for a short duration. Then this sound appears when you plug in a device, like an USB stick, and I cannot click anymore. This affects left, right and middle click, but not the movement of the mouse or the scroll wheel.

I already tried

- Rebooting
- Unplugging and plugging it back in
- Plugin it into a different port
- Uninstalling the device and rebooting
- sfc /scannow . This finds no problems.
- Creating a new user profile. The problem disappears under the new user, but persists under the old one.
- Booting in safe mode. The problem disappears

There are articles on the internet that the user profile might be corrupted, which sounds reasonable to me as the problem only exists under one user profile, but I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: Is the mouse battery powered and wireless, or is it a corded mouse? Have you tried a different mouse? Does the mouse have specific drivers (eg, Logitech) or is it just plug and play?

Comment: It is a corded Logitech, and it does work plug and play. I have not tried an additional mouse (as I only have this one), but I think it works, because it works without flaw under a different user profile.

Comment: While Windows defaults to getting what is usually a good stable driver, a later driver may be what you need. I suggest you find the latest available driver for this mouse from the Logitech site and install that, and see if that fixes the problem. Also, check your Event Viewer for events around the time you hear the plug 'n play connection sound. Those will probably tell you what the computer thinks is going on.

Comment: Rule out a bad connection inside the mouse or the mouse's plug (although the problem disappearing in safe mode suggests that isn't it).  It could be a conflict or incompatibility with something else -- another driver or an application.  The fact that it goes away with a new user also supports that.  Look at what doesn't get loaded for the new user that does for the old user (it also wouldn't be loaded in safe mode).

Comment: How about the driver? just try to uninstall the drive and reinstall the driver and update it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a solution, although I don't fully understand the problem. Uninstalling the "Logitech Gaming Software" fixed the problem. While uninstalling the sound indicating a disconnected device appeared, so this seems to match.

For verification purposes, I reinstalled it, and the problem started again, but only under the same user as before. My guess is that some sort of profile got corrupted, that was not deleted during installation and that is only present for one user.